# A maven build configuration with this name already exists

Tags: java, maven

I am running a `maven build` in eclipse with m2eclipse installed, it shows:

> a maven build configuration with this name already exists.

Where are the configuration files located and can I delete them so that I won't have such naming conflicts further?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right click your project `folder` or `pom.xml`, and `Run as` -> `Run configurations`,
this will open `Run Configurations` `dialog`. you will see the maven build configurations already exists. and delete the duplicates and try again.

hope this helpful.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to eclipse Window - > Preferences -> maven -> Installations and find the maven version installed. If you have multiple versions delete one then Apply and Save then try it.

Answer (score 0):

Coming to the question asked by DehengYe, the configuration files are located at .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core.launches

I have come across the same error message. But, there were no duplicates listed in the dialog "Run Configurations". When I opened the config file folder, I found some ghost launch files present. I call them ghost, because the launch files is present without any entry listed in the "Run Configurations" dialog.

Solution: I stopped Eclipse, deleted the ghost launch files and restarted the Eclipse. Finally, I am able to rename the config in the "Run Configurations" dialog